# Fitting Stacking Classifer when Underlying Models Use Different Feature Subsets

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, fitting, ensemble-learning, stacking

I’m looking to create a stacking classifier based on 3 underlying algorithms. I have already performed feature selection on each of the 3, and each returned a slightly different subset of features for optimal performance.  My issue is I’m now unsure which set of these various x_train values to use to fit the stacking classifier – one of the three subsets, or the full set of features I started with.

I’m new to ensemble models so apologies if this is a basic question, but couldn’t find any previous posts on the topic. Any responses appreciated.

Comment: For how to do this in sklearn, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599700/10495893

Comment: also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539144/232706

Answer (score 1):

The ensemble works by having multiple models and combining their predictions in some way (e.g. a weighted average or some more complex model for combining them). Each of the different initial models that get combined can have different inputs. I.e. they don't need to use the same input features, at all.

If you believe you have created features that work particularly well for one model (e.g. for xgboost you target encoded categorical variables, while for a neural network you used an embedding layer and for random forest you one-hot-encoded; or for linear regression you did kNN imputation and for LightGBM you rely on the build-in method for missing data) or selected a subset of features that works well for each model, then you should probably just give each model those inputs. In fact, it can to some extent be helpful when the different models differ in a lot of ways (as long as they perform still decently well, even better if each performs best with very different approaches in several respects), because ensembling is usually the most effective the more different the predictions of the models are (of course still with the limitation that they need to be somewhat close in performance - adding very bad models that differ a lot does not usually help).

In practice, you might either have a super-set of inputs that then can be fed into all models (that in a way feels neater), or you have a separate training (and validation & test) data derivation for each model (quite common e.g. when in a team in a machine learning competition several team members write their own code and then ensembling is done on top of that - unless runtime becomes an issue it is usually not worth it to refactor the different codebases into a unified one).

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  Could you elaborate a bit on your comment that "you should probably just give each model those inputs" - is there a typical way to do that with a stacking classifier given that I can only fit it on one set of inputs?  And then regardless of the answer to that question, since these feature-selected models tend to produce similar predictions, would it be fair to say that perhaps this is not a situation where a stacking ensemble is particularly helpful? Thanks again; I appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you say that you can only fit one set of inputs? Each initial model can get very different inputs (that's indeed even common in machine learning competitions to have completely separate pipelines for each model), the stacking model the gets the out-of-fold predictions of each model as an input during training. Re: value of stacking, that tends not be huge, but also tends to reliably improve performance by a little bit (so usually done in ML competitions). Even if corrs are high by usual standards (e.g. corrs like 0.5 for predicted probabilities is super low) there's often some gain.

Comment: clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression()

Comment: That's presumably the implementation of some specific library that has its specific limitations?

Comment: Sorry, that prior comment was sent unintentionally. What I meant is (using the example on the SKlearn page), if clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(), when I then call clf.fit(x_train, y_train), do I use (to paraphrase my feature sets) "x_train_all_features", "x_train_subset1", "x_train_subset2" etc. Does that make sense? Understood r.e. benefit of using ensemble even if gains are rather small. Thanks again for your replies, I really appreciate them.